# Beginner, trying to read file returns a null pointer in ubuntu

Tags: c

```
#define max 5
typedef struct
    {
        char tar[20];
        int trab[31];
    }data;

int main()
{
    int i,j, aux;
    char fname[25];
    data inf[max];
    /*for(i=0;i<max;i++)
    {    
           strcpy(inf[i].tar,inf[i-1].tar);
    }*/
    printf("File name?");
    scanf(" %s", fname);
    FILE *f=fopen("fname","r");
    if(f== NULL) 
    {
        printf("Cannot find\n");
        return 1; 
    }
```

I try to read a file I'm very certain is in the same dir, however each time the FILE pointer returns NULL.

I would appreciate any help :(

Comment: `if( (f=fopen(fname, "r")) == NULL ){ perror(fname); ...`  Let the system tell you why it cannot open the file.  Don't just make up an error message.

Answer (score 2):

Although you've tagged this as C++, your code looks more like C, so I'm using a C signature for `main`.  The main problem you have is quotes around `fname`.  Your code is ignoring the path that was entered and trying to open a file with the literal name `fname`.

```
int main(void)
{
    int i,j, aux;
    char fname[25];
    printf("File name? ");
    scanf(" %24s", fname);      /* Always use width specifier on %s */
    FILE *f=fopen(fname, "r");  /* No quotes around fname */
    if( f == NULL ){
        perror(fname);
        return 1; 
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Wow, I feel  so dumb. I swear I spent a full hour comparing my code to examples and stuff, but I guess I gotta keep a sharper eye for these little things. 
Also, the width specifier being 24 instead of 25 is due to the /0, or NULL character at the end of the string right? Thanks alot for answering, first time using stack.

Comment: Yes, the width tells scanf the total number of bytes to consume, and must be one less than the buffer size to allow space for the terminator.

Comment: ''' 
typedef struct
    {
        char tar[20];
        int trab[31];
    }data;
 ...
for(i=0;i<max;i++)
    {
        fscanf(f,"%24s",&inf[i].tar[0]);
        fscanf(f,"%d",&inf[i].trab[0]);
        for(j=1;j<=31;j++){
... '''
I don't know how formating works, but while I was messing with the code yesterday, as I posted, the program told me it couldn't find the file, which I fixed it now. But also afterwards it gave me segmentation fault (core dumped), when entering the fscanf(). Any idea?
Mistyped last comment

Comment: If you have `char tar[20]`, you should use `"%19s"`.  And use `fscanf(f, "%19s", inf[i].tar)`  When you get a core dump, you should analyze it.  It will tell you exactly where the segfault occurred.